# Distributed WSO2 APIM: Problems with KeyManager

Tags: wso2, analytics, api-manager, publisher

Now I am testing the API-Manager doing a distributed install of pruduct.

When I start the Analytitcs and publisher (both in ditributed hosts), the analytic's Log don´t stop to show the error messages:

```
     [2018-04-12 15:00:18,770] ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.databridge.core.internal.queue.QueueWorker} -  Dropping wrongly formatted event sent for -1234
org.wso2.carbon.databridge.core.exception.EventConversionException: Error when converting loganalyzer:1.0.0 of event bundle with events 1
        at org.wso2.carbon.databridge.receiver.thrift.converter.ThriftEventConverter.createEventList(ThriftEventConverter.java:181)
        at org.wso2.carbon.databridge.receiver.thrift.converter.ThriftEventConverter.toEventList(ThriftEventConverter.java:90)
        at org.wso2.carbon.databridge.core.internal.queue.QueueWorker.run(QueueWorker.java:73)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.wso2.carbon.databridge.core.exception.EventConversionException: No StreamDefinition for streamId loganalyzer:1.0.0 present in cache
        at org.wso2.carbon.databridge.receiver.thrift.converter.ThriftEventConverter.createEventList(ThriftEventConverter.java:166)
        ... 7 more
```

Answer (score 1):

This means the APIM (or other product) is sending events with streamId loganalyzer:1.0.0 , however the analytics server has no such stream definition.

The analytics server is effectively a WSO2 DAS with preconfigured streams and analytics related to some other product. The log messages indicates, that the analytics application (org_wso2_carbon_analytics_apim-1.0.0.car) is not (yet) deployed.

It happens commonly when you start up the analytics server, it receives the product (APIM) events before the analytics app is deployed. Once the analytics app is deployed, the DAS should stop logging these messages

So in your case I'd try to have a look on the analytics server in the start of the log file why the analytics application is not properly deployed

Comment: I will try to make the install using version2.2.0..
The version 2.1 have 38 patchs and I don´t have access to it.